# Why would my Silverlight 4 Out-of-Browser application just display white?

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

My **Silverlight** application works **fine** when running in a **browser**.

But when I install it as an **out-of-browser** application, the Window frame comes up with an appropriate icon and title, but the content of the window is **just white**.  It is in the **start menu** but when I close it and open again, it is still blank.

I reproduced this on **Windows 7** and **Windows XP**.

**What could be causing my silverlight application to show only white when running out-of-browser?**

Here are the settings I used:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/rp8ltr.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/rp8ltr.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found it: I had forgotten to wrap some DOM access during initialization which is apparently too early for OOB to show any kind of error, this fixed it:

```
if (!Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
{
   ...
}
```